# Any good free skinable vb.net tab controls?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've been googling and googling for vb.net examples with nice looking tabs.

I really really like this example (slide #4):
http://www.dotnetmagic.com/features_tabbedMDI.html

Has anyone come across any similar free vb.net tab controls with examples? I don't really need the control to be open source, just free :)

Comment: Do you need WPF or Windows Forms controls?

Comment: Windows forms controls is preferred, it's just so easy to work with :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could google the answer, there's some links to get you started:

- [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/), check under desktop development.
- [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) is a known control developer, offers some controls for free.
- [Component Factory](http://www.componentfactory.com) is another good option.

Comment: My vote for component factory for nice little free controls.  Which one did you choose?

Answer (score 1):

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) is probably the best free controls library. And you can find a great TabControl in it. You will have to add it manually to the toolbox.

You have to register for a free license to download it. The download page is still online and working as of 2012-03-22, but cannot be reached by navigation on their website any more:
[Free DevExpress Controls download](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/)

(In an email response they stated this was because they significantly changed their website.
Also, they said these controls can be used royalty-free even in commercial applications, and without having to include any copyright notices.)

Its name is XtraTabControl
Namespace: DevExpress.XtraTab
Assembly: DevExpress.XtraEditor.vXX.X (where XX.X is the version of the XtraEditor, mine is 11.1)

Comment: Though he did ask for "free"... there was a time when devex gave out free licenses for some of their controls (including tab), but I don't see that is still in effect.  If it is, can you link to it?

Comment: i can't seem to find the link. however when i checked i found that my license is still active. try installing any of their products they should contain the XtraEditors Components (Free)

Answer (score 0):

As of Developer Express v2011 vol 2 (at least, probably earlier), the Tab Control is not free. Used to, you could put it on a form and run without a nag screen. Not the case now.

This is the best free one I could find:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/KRBTabControl.aspx